# Обособление обстоятельственного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли первая часть предложения обособленным обстоятельственным оборотом со значением условия? "При использовании в качестве теплоносителя топочных газов(,) тепло передаётся по каналам".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании в качестве теплоносителя топочных газов тепло передаётся по каналам.

**Оборот входит в основное сообщение и не обособляется**,   **дается описание конструкции печей при разных теплоносителях**.

В случае использования в качестве теплоносителя топочных газов тепло передаётся по каналам, а иногда в качестве носителя тепла применяют водяной пар, тогда он подается с помощью специальной трубки.

http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/2890399/

**Пояснение**

Обстоятельственными оборотами обычно называют   обстоятельства при наличии производных предлогов, которые воспринимаются как аналоги придаточных предложений, однако даже их **обособление является факультативным и  зависит от позиции и распространенности.** В данном же случае мы имеем обычное нераспространенное обстоятельство в препозиции, поэтому и нет обособления. Предложение имеет структуру простого предложения вида "тема-рема"(о чем говорится и что говорится), пауза не обозначена, фиксируется только "перелом" интонации на границе двух фраз (восходящего и нисходящего тона). **Всё как в простом предложении без обособленных членов.**

Answer (score 1):

Степень обособленности данного оборота крайне низка (как и вообще у оборотов, имеющих характер прямой, не усложненной пояснительными словами, причинно-следственной или временн**о**й обусловленности), поэтому обособления здесь не требуется.

Но в принципе и обособление ошибкой не будет, поскольку это не противоречит основным принципам пунктуации при обстоятельственных оборотах.